# Can someone explain the Xbox 360 version's battle results screen in more detail?

Tags: xbox-360, world-of-tanks

Being this is the first time I played WOT I don't know all of the details. An as the XBOX 360 version had different looking screens than the PC version if someone could explain the battle results in more detail than the [guide](http://worldoftanksxbox360edition.com/en/content/about/game-guides/general-guide/) it would be helpful.

In particular

- Performance tab: Detected vs Spotted.
- Round tab: The columns with the numbers in them.

Comment: It has more detail because it's a different game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance tab

- **Gamer tag** - The gamer tag of that enemy tank commander.
- **Enemy tank type** - The type of tank the gamer used.
- **Detected** - Where you detected by this enemy tank.
- **Spotter** - Spotted a tank for artillery and the damage done via your action.
- **Damage** - Amount of damage you inflicted on enemy tank.
- **Critical Hits** - How many critical hits you achieved on the enemy tank.
- **Destroyed** - You destroyed the enemy tank. (You may not have inflicted all the damage, but you gave the finishing blow.)

Round tab

- **Gamer tag** - The gamer tag of the tank commander.
- **Tank type** - The type of tank the gamer used.
- **Detected** - Number of enemy tanks that detected that tank.
- **Damage** - The total amount of damage inflicted by that tank on enemy tanks.
- **Destroyed** - The total number of enemy tanks that tank destroyed.
- **Skill points** - The final amount of skill for that tank.
- **Badges** - Any new [badges](http://www.worldoftanksguide.com/ref-achievements.shtml) earned by that tank commander such as sharp shooter.

Comment: I'm fairly certain Detected is actually the opposite, it is the number of tanks that you detected for your team.